# long.tryparse and negative values

Tags: c#

I'm writing a custom JavascriptConverter and I'm testing to see if one the keys received is of type long like this:

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("SomeID"))
{
if (long.TryParse(serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["ContactID"]), out TheTableID))
{...}
```

I only want numbers greater or equal to 0. Do I also need to test if it's a negative number or does the TryParse test for negative numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: can you check to see if the value or object is of ValueType..?

Comment: Austin I may have stated a bit unclear basically he could do something like this 

long myLong = 22;
uint myUint = myLong;        // Error: no implicit conversion from long
uint myUint = (uint)myLong;  // OK: explicit conversion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either have to test for `>= 0`, or use `ulong.TryParse()` instead (which is not really the same thing, but may still fit your needs).

Answer (score 3):

`TryParse` obviously does not check for negative numbers.  After all, `-1234567890` is a valid `long`.

Instead, you can either add `&& TheTableID >= 0` or use `ulong.TryParse` instead.

---

Note that it's better to call `dictionary.TryGetValue` than to make a separate `ContainsKey()` check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, found out about TryGetValue vs ContainsKey: very good tip.

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse` does *not* test for negative numbers, it only tests if the number is a valid `long`.  You will need a separate check, after you parse it, to determine it's sign.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to also test for negative if you only want positive numbers.  TryParse does not test for polarity.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is proper but this could work for you as well based on **Explicit Conversion**

```
long myLong = -22;
uint myUint = (uint)myLong;  // OK: explicit conversion
//yields 4294967274
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zbx0k66.aspx) where you can specify what is a valid number.

```
if (long.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value)
   Console.WriteLine("Long with only digits, no sign, blanks or separators");
```

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) for a decription of the possible NumberStyles flags